# angularjs generating string from attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a little project to generate string based on which class(object) is activated. I want it to work somewhat like this:

> for(i<=30) if(obj[$i]==isActive)?string="x=1":string="x=0"; echo x;

Now i have controller that enables and disables class if object is clicked. How to generate string based on objects that have certain class enabled? to get result like x=1&y=0&z=0&xyz=1. With some reason it is not updating for me

```js
var classApp = angular.module('classApp', []);
classApp.controller('classCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.isActive1 = false;
 $scope.isActive2 = false;
 var build = "";
 if($scope.isActive1==true?build="x=1&":build="x=0&");
 $scope.link = build;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.active {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="classApp" ng-controller="classCtrl">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" ng-class="{'active': isActive1}" ng-click="isActive1 = !isActive1"/> 
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" ng-class="{'active': isActive2}" ng-click="isActive2 = !isActive2"/>
  test={{link}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the angulajs to $scope is changed, you are setting only once in your controller. Need to update at every time using $watch concept.

```js
var classApp = angular.module('classApp', []);
classApp.controller('classCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.isActive1 = false;
 $scope.isActive2 = false;
 var build = "";
 
    $scope.$watch('isActive1', function(newValue) {
      if(newValue==true?build="x=1&":build="x=0&");
          $scope.link = build;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.active {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="classApp" ng-controller="classCtrl">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" ng-class="{'active': isActive1}" ng-click="isActive1 = !isActive1"/> 
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" ng-class="{'active': isActive2}" ng-click="isActive2 = !isActive2"/>
  test={{link}}
</div>
```

Comment: so.. all i had to do is use $watch thing? wow i think i need to read all angular guides once again.
now if I was about to replace string with more variables? how to add something to the string?

Comment: Yeah... u set controller only once, where you called controller, how controller know your scope value changed....